# How to set a blank screen when the app is send to the background

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Does anyone know what I have to do to get a blank screen after sending my application to the background? I have tried the following code, but this is just graying out the views.

```
public void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.idAccLayout);
   for(int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++){
       View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
       child.setEnabled(false);
   }
}
```

Usually this blank screens on pause are in application for banks or trading apps.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean set empty screen in [recents](https://developer.android.com/images/components/recents.png)?

Comment: "Usually this blank screens on pause are in application for banks or trading apps" -- they are frequently using `FLAG_SECURE`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default function for rendering purely white or "blank" in a View. However, using [View#setVisibility(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setVisibility(int)) and [View#GONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#GONE) or [View#INVISIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#INVISIBLE) you can hide your topmost layout (no need to do it for each child) which will cause it to not be rendered anymore. If you background is set to white, this will basically achive a whitescreen.